# ¿Se puede marcar un comentario como respuesta correcta?

Tags: soporte, comentarios, respuesta-aceptada

En una pregunta que realicé tengo un comentario en el que me despeja la duda que tenía. En ese caso es la respuesta correcta, pero no la puedo marcar como correcta (no sé cómo hacerlo).

¿Hay alguna opción para hacerlo así?

> [image: Respuesta correcta]
>
> si usas el CPANEL probablemente es de un tercero y eso no es tan facil cambiar – JackNavaRow el 13 may. a las 18:35

Este comentario fue mi respuesta correcta pero no lo sé marcar como tal.

Comment: Saludos Dave, la  pregunta que realizastes puede verse como irreproducible, generalmente ayudo a los usuarios con la pregunta de ese tipo y le doy al enlace de cerrar pregunta, en caso de tu pregunta es muy puntual y es casi imposible que te ayudemos, y por el bien del sitio para mi deberia ser cerrada.

Comment: @JackNavaRow entiendo, la cerraré.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Un comentario no puede marcarse como respuesta aceptada.

Lo que puedes hacer es:

- Comentarlo al usuario en cuestión y pedirle que publique la respuesta.
- Si después de un tiempo prudencial eso no ocurre, publica tú una respuesta indicando la solución a tu problema. Si es algo extenso puedes seguir lo explicado en [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Si es solamente el comentario, es buena convención social marcarlo como wiki de comunidad.

Answer (score 1):

Ya deje un comentario sobre tu pregunta, pero igual te lo repito aca.

Deberias leer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), para entender como funciona el sitio, y tambien [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para entender mejor como hacer un pregunta.

Tene en cuenta que los comentarios son exactamente eso, comentarios. En tu pregunta hay cosas que no dejaste en claro (por ejemplo, que tu mysql no es tuyo, si no que esta en un servidor en un hosting) y por eso se te dejo ese comentario, mas que todo para que aclares tu escenario completo.

Si el comentario soluciona la pregunta, deberia ponerse como respuesta. Aunque, por como esta planteada tu pregunta, y dado que nunca aclaraste que era un hosting, tu pregunta parece mas algo irreproducible (en su estado actual) que algo que se pueda contestar sin tratar de adivinar que puede estar pasando.

Se aceptan respuestas que son respuestas. Los comentarios son para pedir aclaraciones. Podrias poner vos mismo una respuesta a tu pregunta si con eso se soluciono el problema.

El usuario que te dejo el comentario, no tenia claro si la pregunta se solucionaba con eso, y por eso lo dejo como comentario.

Una respuesta que solo diga no se puede solucionar tampoco seria valida. Por realmente se podria solucionar si estuvieras afuera de un hosting.

Lo que podrias hacer es mejorar la pregunta, donde incluyas toda la información relevante y tambien des una respuesta acorde, donde digas que si estas en un hosting solo se solucionaria si ellos deciden cambiarte la DB (cosa que dudo hagan) o si no, si vos hubieras armado tu DB, explicando como se soluciona.

Comment: Ok, así lo haré.